# Delete complete rows in Excel VBA containing specific data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete complete row which contain the value "THD" in first cell. The content could look like  "THD_C_L10.0W5.0H15.0P7.5" but THD is always there.

I tried it with following loop:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If InStr(1, LCase(Tabelle2.Cells(i, 1)), "THD") <> 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

But unfortunately its not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete rows you have to start your loop from last element and direct into first.
Therefore, instead of:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

you should have something like this:

```
For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 1 Step -1
```

One additional tip which shouldn't affect your current sub- `InStr` has additional parameter which you could use. This line is equivalent to yours one:

```
If InStr(1, Tabelle2.Cells(i, 1), "THD",vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
```